why does imported function do not have access to variables of the scope its being called in?
//a.js
    let func1=function(){
        console.log(p);
    }
    export default export func1;

//index.js
    import func1 from "./a.js";
    let p=1000;
    func1(); 

shows error p is undefined. Why does func1 do not have access to p  (variables of the scope its being called in) ?

Functions ALWAYS have lexical scope. At no point in the history of JS have they had dynamic scope. This is not really about modules or importing.
